# how to allocate more memory to mysql in Windows

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am a MYSQL beginner and I want to allocate more memory to MYSQL.
My machine is Windows 7 64 bit OS with 12GB RAM and Mysql version is 5.6.

Any one can give me the commands to increase memory for MYSQL.

Comment: May be some help here : http://serverfault.com/questions/42789/how-to-increase-memory-usage-in-mysql-server-to-improve-speed or http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Comment: First, make sure MySQL is a 64-bit version.  (Then see the links @PaulF suggests.)

Comment: Thanks to both PaulF & James for your responses. MySQL version also 64 bit. But I am not a DBA and I am unable to follow the instructions on the links. I want to Dedicate 6GB of RAM for MYSQL application. So I am requesting commands for that.

Answer (score 2):

there is a file called my.ini for mysql(windows) which contains

```
'innodb_buffer_pool_size=M'
```

(if no such field you can add explicitly under mysqld tag) where M is MB you can use G for GB increasing this value will solve your purpose and remember to verify using query

```
show variables like '%innodb_buffer_pool_size%';
```